# Why my Photoshop CS3 brushes options doesn't have the "diameter by pressure"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

[image: image showing lines with and without pressure]

The above image shows the lines without pressure and with pressure. I'm newbie, and looks like my photoshop CS3 don't have the "without pressure" option. Follows a printscreen of the brushes options:

[image]

Any idea how to enable the "with pressure" line? Does it exist in Photoshop CS3?

Comment: I've always thought this was a UI brain fart from Adobe... The checkboxes are also menu options. If you have not clicked on the words Shape Dynamics or any of the other ones, I think maybe that's why you can't find the settings :)

Answer (score 2):

If you go just a bit deeper into these options you can find different things you can do and some of them have drop down list which has few other options including "Pen Pressure" which of course works mainly if you have Drawing tablet.

- **Shape Dynamics** - Controlling: Size, Angle and Roundness by pen pressure can be found here.

  - **Minimum Diameter** is what it is.. and Max diameter is what ever the **Master Diameter** is. ( Master diameter is shown in your own screenshot. )

    ---
- **Other Dynamics** - Controlling: Opacity and Flow Jitter can be found here.

[image]

Comment: The Pen Pressure option also affects the stroke when you choose "Simulate Pressure" when you apply a stroke to a Path using "Stroke Path..." from the Paths Panel flyout menu.

Answer (score -2):

I think you want the pressure settings because you have a tablet, like a wacom or something else...

Have a look at this video :

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vy_8k4Buwng

I think it will help.

Hope this helps... If you dont have a tablet... then probably you are looking for something else, not pressure settings... cause you cannot apply pressure with the mouse, i tried it, doesn't work no matter how hard you press the click :P